# How to load messages on mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a page in my Web project which shows messages loaded from the database like this:

```
 @foreach (var message in Model.Messages)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="message">
                                @message.Instance
                            </td>                                
                        </tr>
                    }
```

So how can I load for example 30 messages using LINQ `Model.Messages.Take(30)`, every time when user is scrolling Up page

**Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450304/load-data-on-scroll-up-like-facebook-chatting-system), thnx for attention!**

Comment: You have to bind a an event on window's `onscroll` and check if user scrolled, then you load the next messages.. basically.

Comment: You might search with the term [lazy loading](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=asp.net+mvc+jquery+lazy+loading&oq=asp.net+mvc+jquery+lazy+loading&aqs=chrome..69i57.15735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick sample code to test

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();

    //check for scrollposition and height
    if(scrollPosition >= scrollHeight - 100)
    {
        //here load next messages
        loadNext();
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm scrolling, but nothing happens, function doesn't call

Comment: Can you attach your fiddle link for test?

Comment: Here is the text fiddle link I have created. https://jsfiddle.net/trupti11/t9jvLjsb/

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS solution:

```js
var currentScroll = document.body.scrollTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  if (document.body.scrollTop < currentScroll) {
    // Load messages on scroll up
    console.log('scroll up');
  }

  currentScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Js solution

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(".chat-area").on("scroll", function (e) {
        let st = $(this).scrollTop(); //get current scroll position
        if(st < (lastScrollTop * 0.1)) { // if current position is in top 10$ of chat area make a call
        if(can_Scroll) { 
        can_Scroll = 0;// no more ajax calls until server responds with messages 
        fetchOldMessages(ajax call or function);}

    }
       lastScrollTop = st;

});
```